# How to interpret PostgreSQL EXPLAIN results when query hangs

Tags: postgresql

I have no idea how to simplify this problem, so this is going to be a long question.

For openers, for reasons I won't get into, I normalized out long paragraphs to a table named `shared.notes`.

Next I have a complicated view with a number of paragraph lookups. Each note_id field is (a) indexed and (b) has a foreign key constraint to the notes table. Pseudo code below:

```
CREATE VIEW shared.vw_get_the_whole_kit_and_kaboodle AS
SELECT
    yada yada

  , mi.electrical_note_id
  , electrical_notes.note AS electrical_notes
  , mi.hvac_note_id
  , hvac_notes.note AS hvac_notes
  , mi.network_note_id
  , network_notes.note AS network_notes
  , mi.plumbing_note_id
  , plumbing_notes.note AS plumbing_notes
  , mi.specification_note_id
  , specification_notes.note AS specification_notes
  , mi.structural_note_id
  , structural_notes.note AS structural_notes

FROM shared.a_table AS mi
JOIN shared.generic_items AS gi
  ON mi.generic_item_id = gi.generic_item_id
JOIN shared.manufacturers AS mft
  ON mi.manufacturer_id = mft.manufacturer_id
JOIN shared.notes AS electrical_notes
  ON mi.electrical_note_id = electrical_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.notes AS hvac_notes
  ON mi.hvac_note_id = hvac_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.notes AS plumbing_notes
  ON mi.plumbing_note_id = plumbing_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.notes AS specification_notes
  ON mi.specification_note_id = specification_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.notes AS structural_notes
  ON mi.structural_note_id = structural_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.notes AS network_notes
  ON mi.network_note_id = network_notes.note_id
JOIN shared.connectivity AS nc
  ON mi.connectivity_id = nc.connectivity_id
WHERE
  mi.deletion_date IS NULL;
```

Then I select against this view:

```
SELECT
  lots of columns...
FROM shared.vw_get_the_whole_kit_and_kaboodle
WHERE 
  is_active = TRUE
  AND is_inventory = FALSE;
```

Strangely, in the cloud GCP databases, I've not run into problems yet, and there are thousands of rows involved in a number of these tables.

Meanwhile back at the ranch, on my local PC, I've got a test version of the database. SAME EXACT SQL, down to the last letter. Trust me on that. For table definitions, view definitions, indexes... everything.

The cloud will return queries nearly instantaneously.

The local PC will hang--this despite the fact that the PC database has a mere handful of rows each in the various tables. So if one should hang, it ought to be the cloud databases. But it's the other way around; the tiny-dataset database is the one that fails.

Add this plot twist in: if I remove the filter for is_inventory, the query on the PC returns instantaneously. Also, if I just remove, one by one, the joins to the notes table, after about half of them are gone, the PC starts to finish instantaneously. It's almost like it's upset to be hitting the same table so many times with one query.

If I run `EXPLAIN` (without the `ANALYZE` option), here's the NO-hang version:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=31.55..40.09 rows=43 width=751)
 Hash Cond: (mi.mounting_location_id = ml.mounting_location_id)
 ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=30.34..38.76 rows=43 width=719)
  Hash Cond: (mi.price_type_id = pt.price_type_id)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=29.25..37.53 rows=43 width=687)
   Hash Cond: (mi.connectivity_id = nc.connectivity_id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.16..36.21 rows=43 width=655)
    Join Filter: (mi.network_note_id = network_notes.note_id)
    ->  Seq Scan on notes network_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.16..34.66 rows=43 width=623)
     Join Filter: (mi.plumbing_note_id = plumbing_notes.note_id)
     ->  Seq Scan on notes plumbing_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=28.16..33.11 rows=43 width=591)
      Hash Cond: (mi.generic_item_id = gi.generic_item_id)
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=5.11..9.95 rows=43 width=559)
       Hash Cond: (mi.structural_note_id = structural_notes.note_id)
       ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.09..8.57 rows=43 width=527)
        Hash Cond: (mi.specification_note_id = specification_notes.note_id)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.07..7.37 rows=43 width=495)
         Hash Cond: (mi.hvac_note_id = hvac_notes.note_id)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.04..5.99 rows=43 width=463)
          Hash Cond: (mi.electrical_note_id = electrical_notes.note_id)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.02..4.70 rows=43 width=431)
           Hash Cond: (mi.manufacturer_id = mft.manufacturer_id)
           ->  Seq Scan on mft_items mi  (cost=0.00..3.44 rows=43 width=399)
            Filter: ((deletion_date IS NULL) AND is_active)
           ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
            ->  Seq Scan on manufacturers mft  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
          ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
            ->  Seq Scan on notes electrical_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
          ->  Seq Scan on notes hvac_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
         ->  Seq Scan on notes specification_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
       ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
        ->  Seq Scan on notes structural_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
      ->  Hash  (cost=15.80..15.80 rows=580 width=48)
       ->  Seq Scan on generic_items gi  (cost=0.00..15.80 rows=580 width=48)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
    ->  Seq Scan on connectivity nc  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
   ->  Seq Scan on price_types pt  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
 ->  Hash  (cost=1.09..1.09 rows=9 width=48)
  ->  Seq Scan on mounting_locations ml  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=48)
```

And this is the hang version:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=26.43..38.57 rows=16 width=751)
 Hash Cond: (mi.mounting_location_id = ml.mounting_location_id)
 ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=25.23..37.32 rows=16 width=719)
  Hash Cond: (mi.price_type_id = pt.price_type_id)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=24.14..36.18 rows=16 width=687)
   Hash Cond: (mi.connectivity_id = nc.connectivity_id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..35.00 rows=16 width=655)
    Join Filter: (mi.network_note_id = network_notes.note_id)
    ->  Seq Scan on notes network_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..33.79 rows=16 width=623)
     Join Filter: (mi.structural_note_id = structural_notes.note_id)
     ->  Seq Scan on notes structural_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..32.58 rows=16 width=591)
      Join Filter: (mi.electrical_note_id = electrical_notes.note_id)
      ->  Seq Scan on notes electrical_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..31.37 rows=16 width=559)
       Join Filter: (mi.specification_note_id = specification_notes.note_id)
       ->  Seq Scan on notes specification_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..30.16 rows=16 width=527)
        Join Filter: (mi.plumbing_note_id = plumbing_notes.note_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on notes plumbing_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..28.95 rows=16 width=495)
         Join Filter: (mi.hvac_note_id = hvac_notes.note_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on notes hvac_notes  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.05..27.74 rows=16 width=463)
          Join Filter: (mi.manufacturer_id = mft.manufacturer_id)
          ->  Seq Scan on manufacturers mft  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=48)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.05..26.53 rows=16 width=431)
           Hash Cond: (mi.generic_item_id = gi.generic_item_id)
           ->  Seq Scan on mft_items mi  (cost=0.00..3.44 rows=16 width=399)
            Filter: ((deletion_date IS NULL) AND is_active AND (NOT is_inventory))
           ->  Hash  (cost=15.80..15.80 rows=580 width=48)
            ->  Seq Scan on generic_items gi  (cost=0.00..15.80 rows=580 width=48)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
    ->  Seq Scan on connectivity nc  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
   ->  Seq Scan on price_types pt  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=36)
 ->  Hash  (cost=1.09..1.09 rows=9 width=48)
  ->  Seq Scan on mounting_locations ml  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=48)
```

I'd like to understand what I should be doing differently to escape this hang condition. Unfortunately, I'm not clear on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just curious, what if you didn't use a view but included it as a CTE - does the query still hang?

Comment: Also, and probably more likely - has something [been locked](https://blog.brkn.io/2019/02/18/fix-hanging-postgres-queries.html)?

Comment: if I use a CTE like this `SELECT * FROM (WITH mi AS (SELECT *  FROM shared.a_table WHERE is_active = TRUE AND is_inventory = FALSE) SELECT ...` the query returns instantly. And that being the case, that also rules out lock problems, you'd agree?

Comment: Almost certainly yes, that should rule out lock problems. I'd still check pg_locks in another session while the hanging query is going to make sure (should be nothing with granted=false). Also, check if the backend process is spinning CPU - that's what I would expect if it's not a lock problem.

Comment: No, I don't *think* it rules out lock problems entirely, it just means the lock problems, if that's what this is, aren't happening unless you use the view (just spitballing, wouldn't consider myself a PG expert by any stretch).

Comment: Is there a vacuum going on, by any chance, when you generate the view? I'm trying to think about what would block a select AND something that could be different in the cloud configuration vs local.

Comment: if by spinning CPU you mean the fan starts spinning furiously and CPU usage pegs out at 100%... Yes. Those are among the hallmarks of my hangs. I don't think VACUUM is involved because this is just a local PC with no special jobs running. I'm not initiating any VACUUM calls.

Comment: I can hear the fan warming up, CPU is pegged out, and I run this... ```select nspname, relname, l.* from pg_locks l  join pg_class c on (relation = c.oid) join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) where pid in (select pid from pg_stat_activity where datname = current_database() and query != current_query());``` and all rows returned have granted = true. So... no locking problems, then? I, too, am not a PG expert by any stretch. Less so than you, it's clear, but I'm following your suggestions. ;)